# ¿Como validar cuantos checkbox fueron clickeados y mostrar mensaje de error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema para validar checkboxes.

Mi template cuenta con 5 modales distintos para cada uno de los productos en mi negocio.

Dentro de cada modal el usuario debe seleccionar los gustos de helado que desee, pero cada producto admite un minimo de 0 y un maximo de N gustos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   <!-- Modales -->
    <div id="vasoModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Vasito</h4>
            <h6>Seleccione hasta dos gustos</h6>
            <form id="vasitoForm" method="post">
                <table class="tabla">
                        <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                            <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                            <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}" name="box"/></td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="formVasito" value="vasito" />
                        </tr>
                </table>
                <p id="errorModalVasito"></p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cucuModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Cucurucho</h4>
                <h6>Seleccione hasta dos gustos</h6>
                <form id="cucuForm" method="post">
                    <table class="tabla">
                        <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                            <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                            <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}" name="box"/></td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="formCucu" value="cucurucho" />
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p id="errorModalCucu"></p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cuartoModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">1/4 Kilo</h4>
                <h6>Seleccione hasta dos gustos</h6>
                <form id="cuartoForm" method="post">
                    <table class="tabla">
                        <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                            <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                            <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}" name="box"/></td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="formCuarto" value="cuarto" />
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p id="errorModalCuarto"></p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="medioModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">1/2 Kilo</h4>
                <h6>Seleccione hasta tres gustos</h6>
                <form id="medioForm" method="post">
                    <table class="tabla">
                        <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                            <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                            <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}" name="box"/></td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="formMedio" value="medio" />
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p id="errorModalMedio"></p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="kiloModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">1 Kilo</h4>
                <h6>Seleccione hasta cuatro gustos</h6>
                <form id="kiloForm" method="post">
                    <table class="tabla">
                        <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                            <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                            <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}" name="box"/></td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="formKilo" value="kilo" />
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p id="errorModalKilo"></p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Vasito --- maximo 2 gustos

Cucurucho --- maximo 2 gustos

Cuarto --- maximo 2 gustos

Medio --- maximo 3 gustos

Kilo --- maximo 4 gustos

Estoy intentando de hacerlo así pero no me funciona:

```
/* Validar checkboxes clickeados */
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.single-checkbox');
var clickeados = new Array();
var checked = 0;

checkboxes.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if(elem.checked) {
           if(!clickeados.includes(elem)){
                   clickeados.push(elem);
           }
           checked ++;
           console.log(checked);
        }
        else{
            if(clickeados.includes(elem)){
                   clickeados.pop(elem);
            }
            checked --;
            console.log(checked);
        }
    });
});

/* Validar cuantos gustos fueron seleccionados antes de hacer el submit */
const formVasito = document.getElementById('vasitoForm');
if(checked > 0 && checked < 3){
    formVasito.addEventListener('submit',(event) => {
       const seleccionados = new FormData(formVasito);
       var formName = document.getElementById('formVasito').value;
      $('#vasitoForm').attr('action', seleccionados + '/' + formName + '/pedido');
    });
}
else{
    document.getElementById('errorModalVasito').innerHTML = "Debe seleccionar hasta dos gustos";
}
```

Los checked por consola me salen bien, osea, reconoce los checked y unchecked pero cuando se hace el submit vuelve a la misma página, cosa que no debería, osea algo va mal con la lógica :(

Alguna idea ?

Comment: Es un comentario: porque necesitas tantos modales? Probablemente el formulario es lo mismo para para todos los modales. Podrías añadir un `select` par vasito, cucurucho . . . etc. El numero máximo de gustos aparecería al seleccionar si es "vasito" u otra cosa. Lo mismo para `<h4>`

Comment: Si, tenés razon ... sinceramente soy nuevo programando y estoy más que nada practicando el código en si sin darle tanta bola tal vez a la arquitectura, pero a mi también me hizo ruido la repetición ... gracias por la observación. Cuando tenga todo listo la idea es corregir las cosas como estas para seguir aprendiendo ... Gracias :)